# Fetch Request: error . . . Core Data Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swift3

Good Night;

Im creating an app that would save the name of people in a Core Data file, when I run the app and save what the user typed it works fine when I load (fetch ) the data it also works fine, the problem comes when I close or go to a different view controller when I hit the load data(fetch) the app crashed with : 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error: 
 is not a valid NSFetchRequest.'

this is my code

```html
 @IBOutlet var PresidentTxt: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet var SecDefenseTxt: UITextField!
  
    
    let dataStack = CoreDataStack()
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    
    
    @IBAction func Save(_ sender: Any) {
    
   
        
        
        let database = dataStack.persistenContainer.viewContext
        
        let dbrRecord = Command(context: database)
        
        dbrRecord.potus = PresidentTxt.text
        dbrRecord.defsec = SecDefenseTxt.text
        
        do{
        
        try database.save()
        
        
        }catch {}
        
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    func didTapView(){
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func Load(_ sender: Any) {
   
   
        
        let database = dataStack.persistenContainer.viewContext
        
        do{
            
            let results = try database.fetch(Command.fetchRequest()) as! [Command]
            
            for presidentUS in results{
                if let _ = presidentUS.potus {
                
                    PresidentTxt.text = presidentUS.potus
                    
                }
            
            }
            
            for DefenseSec in results {
            
                if let _ = DefenseSec.defsec {
                
                    SecDefenseTxt.text = DefenseSec.defsec
                
                }
            
                
                
                
                
                
            }
        
        
        
        
        
        
        }catch {}
   
        

    }
```